# Импорт товаров с 1с на сайт Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5

День добрый всем
Стояла задача осуществить импорт товаров с 1С программы для учета на сайт
Столкнулся с проблемой не правильной генерации названия на сайте
В данный момент на сайте отображается название как **Накладка-аккумулятор WK-DESIGN WP-020 iphone 7 (золотистый)**

А должно быть так **Чехол аккумулятор для iPhone 7 WK-DESIGN WP-020 (золотистый) 2400 mAh**

Вот кусок кода из xml файла который появляется при обмене данными между сервером и 1С

```
<Описание>Накладка-аккумулятор WK-DESIGN WP-020 iphone 7 (золотистый)</Описание> !!!!
                <ЗначенияСвойств>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>548370ee-3a90-11e3-9566-00144f9b870d</Ид>
                        <Значение>WK-DESIGN</Значение>                          !!!
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>548370f0-3a90-11e3-9566-00144f9b870d</Ид>
                        <Значение>Аксессуары</Значение>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>548370f2-3a90-11e3-9566-00144f9b870d</Ид>
                        <Значение>WP-020</Значение>                             !!!
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>548370f4-3a90-11e3-9566-00144f9b870d</Ид>
                        <Значение>Чехол</Значение>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>33432d98-3b06-11e3-9566-00144f9b870d</Ид>
                        <Значение>Чехол аккумулятор для iPhone 7 WK-DESIGN WP-020 </Значение>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>c6ed7052-3e67-11e3-9567-00144f9b870d</Ид>
                        <Значение>(золотистый) 2400 mAh</Значение>              !!!
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>18faa0b4-de76-11e6-80ff-d017c2adc088</Ид>
                        <Значение>Да</Значение>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>ba09b430-334a-11e7-8102-d017c2adc088</Ид>
                        <Значение>Золотистый</Значение>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                </ЗначенияСвойств>
```

Вот метод импорта в файле php

```
protected function product()
    {
        $name = $this->importProduct->Наименование;

        foreach ($this->importProduct->ЗначенияРеквизитов->ЗначениеРеквизита as $item) {
            switch ($item->Наименование){
                case 'Вес':
                    $weight = $item->Значение;
                    break;
                case 'ВесБрутто':
                    $grossWeight = $item->Значение;
                    break;
                case 'Ширина':
                    $width = $item->Значение;
                    break;
                case 'Длина':
                    $length = $item->Значение;
                    break;
                case 'Высота':
                    $height = $item->Значение;
                    break;
                case 'Доп Характеристика':
                    $attr = $item->Значение;
                    break;
                case 'НовыйТовар':
                    $is_new = $item->Значение == 'Нет' ? 0 : 1;
                    break;
                
            }
        }

        if (! $this->importProduct->{'Группы'}) {
            Log::info('empty_groups');
            return false;
        }

        $this->product = Product::updateOrCreate([
            'id_1c' => $this->importProduct->Ид,
        ], [
            'name' => trim($name),
            'category_id'   => $this->getCategoryId(),
            'weight'        => $weight ?? '',
            'grossWeight'   => $grossWeight ?? '',
            'width'         => $width ?? '',
            'length'        => $length ?? '',
            'height'        => $height ?? '',
            'attr'          => $attr ?? '',
            'is_new'        => $is_new ?? '',
        ]);

        if (!$this->product->description) {
            $this->product->update(['description' => $this->importProduct->Описание]);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Может кто то знает или сталкивался с подобной проблемой буду признателен за любую информацию

Answer (score 0):

Вариант простой: попросить программиста из 1С выгружать вместо

```
<Описание>Накладка-аккумулятор WK-DESIGN WP-020 iphone 7 (золотистый)</Описание>
```

```
<ЗначенияСвойства>
  <Ид>33432d98-3b06-11e3-9566-00144f9b870d</Ид>
  <Значение>Чехол аккумулятор для iPhone 7 WK-DESIGN WP-020 </Значение>
</ЗначенияСвойства>
```

чтобы на выходе получилось:

```
<Описание>Чехол аккумулятор для iPhone 7 WK-DESIGN WP-020</Описание>
```

Вариант 2: если доступа к 1С программистам нет.
Брать в обмене название из свойства.

```
<ЗначенияСвойства>
  <Ид>33432d98-3b06-11e3-9566-00144f9b870d</Ид>
  <Значение>Чехол аккумулятор для iPhone 7 WK-DESIGN WP-020 </Значение>
</ЗначенияСвойства>
```

При условии что `<Ид>33432d98-3b06-11e3-9566-00144f9b870d</Ид>` не изменен во всех товарах.